# Hibernate criteria: search by content on a property list in an entity

Tags: java, hibernate, filter, criteria, restrictions

I want to search by content on a property in an entity

I have a simple class to define a User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "pers_id")
    private int persId; 

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;    

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERS_ID")
    private List<UserLanguages> languages = new ArrayList<UserLanguages>();
}
```

A User can have multiple languages, here is the class to make the link between user and a language.

```
@Entity
public class UserLanguages {
    @Column(name="pers_id")
    private int persId; 

    @Id
    @Column(name="lang_iso_code")
    private String langISO;

    @Column(name="lang_full_name")
    private String langFullName;

    @Column(name="order_seq")
    private int order;
}

@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id 
    @Column(name="ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")  
    private String code;
}
```

I have created a object to do search:

```
public class UserFilter {    
    private String name;

    private List<Language> languages;
}
```

I have defined a service:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Override
public List<User> findByFilter(UserFilter userFilter) {
    final Criteria criteria = userDao.createCriteria();
    if (userFilter.getName() != null) {
        for (final String token : userFilter.getName().toLowerCase().trim().split(" ")) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("fullName", "%" + token + "%"));
        }
    }

    if (null != userFilter.getLanguages() && userFilter.getLanguages().size() > 0) {

        final List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>(userFilter.getLanguages().size());
        for (final Language lang : userFilter.getLanguages()) {
        contents.add(lang.getCode());
        }    
        criteria.add(Restrictions.in("languages", contents));
    }

    return userDao.findByCriteria(criteria);
}
```

My question is how can I do search on languages. I want to find all users with this or thoses languages defined in the userFilter param.
The part about languages doesn't work in the method findByFilter in the service. Can you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the `UserLanguages` entity should be named `UserLanguage` : it represents one language, and not several.

Then, the `pers_id` column is a foreign key to the `User` entity. It should thus be mapped as a ManyToOne relationship to the User entity rather than a basic column.

Finally, and to answer your question (I'll assume you want to find the users having at least one user language whose `langISO` code is in the `contents` list) : you should use a join :

```
// inner join between User and UserLanguages
criteria.createAlias("languages", "userLanguage"); 
// restriction on the langISO property of UserLanguage
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("userLanguage.langIso", contents));
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have changed UserLanguages to UserLanguage, you right. Now, I used the ManyToOne relation. But I don't understand where come from the language.langIso in the last Restrictions?

Comment: Sorry. I forget the double quotes and the user prefix. I updated my answer.